# Call Smarty php function from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, smarty

I want to call smarty PHP function from `smarty.tpl` on the change event of a `dropdown`. Is it possible through ajax? Or any other easy go for that?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a template module on top of php. So basically smarty functions are php functions. You don't need ajax to call it, you can call it directly, you just need to register it.

Here is how to do it: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.register.function.tpl

Comment: But i have to use onchange event of thre dropdown . So i have to use ajax

Comment: So you want to call a php function from js? You can't do that since js is client side and php is server side. You indeed need to make an ajax request. But in this case you need to describe what you want to do in... more than 2 lines of text :).

Comment: In my case, there is a category selector(dropdown) in the smarty template. There may be parent categories and sub categories. I have to collect category data according to the selected category.for example display number of products in each category  in a textbox

Comment: So you actually need to dynamically load another page inside a specified container. Ajax is the only way to do this. You call a script that loads a template and in that template you display whatever you need to. Just one note, the scripts on that template (if any) will not be computed by default.